# XBian increase buffert

Tags: networking, wireless, xbian

I've got a Raspberry Pi with Wi-Pi and XBian installed. All works great until I try to look at high def 720p over wireless network. Is there a way to tweak the original settings to increase the network buffer? I have not yet tried to change gpu_mem.

Comment: It might not do a difference?

Comment: What protocol are you using to share the media over the network? http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=Raspberry_Pi/FAQ#Performance:_video_buffering.2C_stuttering.2C_choppiness

Answer (score 1):

Edit the advancedsettings.xml

```
nano /home/xbian/.xbmc/userdata/advancedsettings.xml
```

Change the  value to something bigger. It's in bytes.

Reference here http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=advancedsettings.xml